# WordPress Comment form making screen go blank

Tags: wordpress

Okay I need help. I have broken my head back and forth and I cant solve the issue.

I created my comments.php file in my theme it contains the following:

```
<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
<br />
<br />
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

When I call for it everything works fine. My issue is when I click in the textarea to leave a comment it triggers my page and the whole page goes blank. Not sure what is causing this? Any suggestions??

You can check it our here: http://labpixls.com/nulla-sagittis-convallis-arcu-9/

Comment: your question is too specific and after looking through your page, i can assure you it's some javascript problem, might involves with your `fancy_placeholder` stuff, you have to learn to debug this and provide  detail investigation so we can better help

Comment: in your wordpress root directory search n open `wp-config.php` in this file look for `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and change it to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` now you can see error flashing on the page instead of a blank page

Comment: Thank guys, I'm going to give this a try on my wp-config file and review my javascript code. Ill report my findings.

Comment: @JasonArroyo: Look at my answer as well & try those suggestions. & Post your debugging results as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information for a comprehensive answer but here are some suggestions for you, may be it can help.

First of all, turn on Wordpress Debugging by changing `'WP_DEBUG'` option from `false` to `true` in wp-config.php, it will display errors encountered on page

Secondly, i think it would be some sort of javascript conflict issue. Try loading site without extra .js files like if you are using some plugins, try deactivating them and check if it helps because it seems to me a `js` issue that triggers that blank page

Once again, your question didn't provide enough information, so please try these & debug as well. Once you do debugging, post those details & may be i can help more.

I hope it helps -

Comment: Thanks, Shumail Mohy-ud-Din. It, looks like you are correct. It's javascript related. I turned off all my plug ins and it no longer creates a blank screen. I starting to think it could be cause I have too many plug ins in my .js file. I am going to separate them into individual js files and track down my bad plug in. I'll report back my final solution so hopefully it may help someone else.

Comment: @JasonArroyo: That's Good. Please Accept my answer & mark it as accepted answer. To accept answer, click the TICK sign under Votes counter to left side of my answer. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Interesting bug! It appears that something is actually deleting the entire `<body>` element onclick. It's not tied to the comment form because the same issue occurs when you click the Category dropdown on the right and some other places on the page. It's definitely an issue with FancyBox because, if you set event listeners for onClick and mousedown, you can get it to spit out a `Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong.` before it deletes everything.

I can track it back to this line `plugins.js:3155`:

```
if (F.open(what, options) !== false) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

From here, however, I'm unsure. My recommendation would be to make sure that you're using the latest version of FancyBox, see if they have any similar reported issues, and try and find a replacement if all else fails.

Hope that was helpful.

**Edit** I don't know what changed, but I'm not able to reproduce the error now. If you fixed it, please let us know what you did.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. The issue is still present. The good news is indeed it's Fancybox causing the issue. Still not to sure why Fancy box has decided to break and create the entire content section in an anchor that is causing the page to go blank when clicking anywhere in the content area. I'm reviewing all my code to see what is breaking. But the code looks good. If, anyone wants to help trouble shoot let me know I can email you the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Okay everyone. I have finally track down the issue. I was using .single as my class on my anchor tag which held the image path to the full size image. I overlooked that wordpress creates a "single" class in the body. So that was causing the issue. When you would click anywhere in the body it would trigger fancybox. Solution rename my class to lrgimg